# Calling a log of missed numbers?

Tags: java, android

I'm a noob who's working on his first app. Imagine you're busy and not able to pick up some calls during the day. The app shows you a log of the calls you missed, and you can start calling them with a single button click. Not all at once - you start with the first missed number, automatically come back to the app when the call is finished, automatically dial the second number, and so on until the list is empty or you're done calling. This is my what my app looks like right now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHGQW.jpg

I log missed calls and display them, and I have a "start calling" button that's supposed to start the loop. I'm not sure how to make it so that the onClick starts calling missed call no1, then missed call no2 etc and I haven't found much about it though my Google game isn't very strong yet. This is how I get the call details:

```
public String getCallDetails() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

//        if 
// (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), 
// Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != 
// PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//
//            return ;
//        }

    Cursor managedCursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");

    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

    sb.append("\n");

    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);

        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }

        // Getting the current date and time using the date class
        Date d = new Date();

        if (dir == "MISSED") {

            sb.append("\n   Phone Number: " + phNumber + " \n   Call Date: " + callDayTime + "\n");
            sb.append("   ---------------------------------------------------\n \n");

        }
    }

    managedCursor.close();
    return sb.toString();

}
```

And this is my button onClick:

```
callBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {

//                    String phone = ????
// Using the ACTION.CALL intent, you're going straight to the first 
// call                      
//                    Intent callIntent = new 
//                    Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.fromParts("tel", 
//                    phone, null));

                // Check for permission, write yes/no etc. here
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                            UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission granted! Thank you!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(callIntent, "callTitle"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no, your call has failed!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm also trying to filter it so that only missed calls from the past two days are showing, but that's something for later. Just wondering what's a good way to call-loop through the missed calls right now.

Any pointers are welcome!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Phone State Listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_CALL_STATE) to listen call states. Whenever call states returns to [STATE_IDLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_IDLE) you can go for next calls.

Dont forget to stop listining state when you are done.